# npm module tests

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm planning on releasing a Node module out in the wild and was wondering if I should include tests written specifically for use with a test framework (i.e mocha) or tests that run with regular node (i.e node test.js).

What's the consensus on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't go too far wrong following some of the biggest projects in the ecosystem

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/test
https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/tree/master/test
https://github.com/LearnBoost/websocket.io/tree/master/test